# How to fix this simple program in JAVA? guessing game

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Its my first year in college and i need to fix this program for my homework. How do i get the program to loop back for another input after the user has entered his/her first guess?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class Guessing {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX = 20;
    int answer, guess, lowcount = 0, highcount = 0;
    String sguess;
    Random generator = new Random();
    answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
    do {
      sguess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and " + MAX + ". Guess what it is: ");
      guess = Integer.parseInt(sguess);

      if (guess > answer) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is TOO HIGH!");
        highcount++;
        break;
      } else if (guess < answer) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is TOO LOW!");
        lowcount++;
        break;
      }
    }
    while (guess != answer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Take out the two `break;` statements.

Comment: What in the name of all things holy does your question have to do with Javascript or C++? You're spamming programming tags. Please don't do this, unless your goal is to attract non-Java experts to your question thereby pissing them off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the break statements in your 'do-while' loop.